# Searching in MongoDB inside a String

Tags: mongodb

I am new to MongoDB world and have some basic questions. I wanted to find out if it is possible to search withing a string in MongoDB. For example here is a record:

> db.test.insert({ s_id:0, c_id:1, json:"{result:[104192,42068],id:1}" })

When I do a find on s_id it works fine:

> db.test.findOne({s_id:0})
>   {
>           "_id" : ObjectId("511d1675d3c6fdeb779c8ea8"),
>           "s_id" : 0,
>           "c_id" : 1,
>           "json" : "{result:[104192,42068],id:1}"
>   }

However, if I do a find on json : "result" it does not work

> db.test.findOne({json : "result"})
>   null

At the same time I did ensure Index on json

> db.test.ensureIndex({json:1})

Is it possible to do a search on such string within or do we need to create a SOLR or Elastic Search on top of this?

Any pointers are highly appreciated

Thanks
Masti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So values for your json key are serialized json.  If you're searching for documents having json values containing the word 'result', you can use a $regex operator. You don't indicate how many records you have or what performance you're expecting, so possibly Solr / Lucene might be overkill.  You could also look into the new free text search features in the very latest MongoDB version.

Try:

```
db.test.find({json:/result:/i});
```

On my machine:

```
> db.test.insert({ s_id:0, c_id:1, json:"{result:[104192,42068],id:1}" })
> db.test.find({json:/result:/i});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("511d21fe0ff85d1b95a5f8b1"), "s_id" : 0, "c_id" : 1, "json" : "{result:[104192,42068],id:1}" }
```

Incidentally, from the MongoDB manual:

"$regex can only use an index efficiently when the regular expression has an anchor for the beginning (i.e. ^) of a string and is a case-sensitive match"

So you actually probably want

```
> db.test.ensureIndex({json:1})
> db.test.find({json:{ $regex:'^{result:'}}).explain();
{
    "cursor" : "BtreeCursor json_1 multi",
    "isMultiKey" : false,
    "n" : 1,
    "nscannedObjects" : 1,
    "nscanned" : 1,
    "nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1,
    "nscannedAllPlans" : 1,
    "scanAndOrder" : false,
    "indexOnly" : false,
    "nYields" : 0,
    "nChunkSkips" : 0,
    "millis" : 0,
    "indexBounds" : {
        "json" : [
            [
                "",
                {

                }
            ],
            [
                /^{result:/,
                /^{result:/
            ]
        ]
    },
    "server" : "Micks-MacBook-Pro-3.local:27017"
}
```

Comment: Note that in addition to this there is the newly added text search feature.  Here is a link to a blog post showcasing this new feature:   http://blog.mongodb.org/post/40513621310/mongodb-text-search-experimental-feature-in-mongodb

Comment: Hence my comment in the first para of my answer :)

Answer (score 0):

This link covers read operation basics in Mongo rather well: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/read/

Edit: Searching in Mongo using more complex queries is not recommended in big databases. If you regularly want to do so, consider an index like solr. Mongo is best searched using id.